# How can heat generation be $V*I$ when the total power available to a circuit is $V*I$?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

If joules law says rate of heat generation in a circuit is $V*I$, but the total power available to a circuit is also $V*I$, then all power in a circuit must go to heat. How can this be possible if a motor does mechanical work?

Answer (score 4):

Joule’s law only applies to resistors. It doesn’t apply to other devices like capacitors, inductors, motors, antennas, diodes, etc.

Comment: It applies to capacitors and inductors in the sense that if you find $VI$ is imaginary, then you have reactive power only and no heat (or oter net power conversion to another form) is produced.

Comment: @ThePhoton https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating “passage of an electric current through a conductor”, https://www.britannica.com/science/Joules-law “into heat energy by the resistance”, https://byjus.com/physics/joules-law/ “resistance in a circuit converts electric energy”, https://www.vedantu.com/physics/joules-law “in a conductor the amount of heat generated”, etc.

Comment: similarly, Ohm's law is only about conductors/resistors, but we extend it using the impedance concept to apply to inductors and capacitors in steady-state AC conditions.

Comment: @ThePhoton I understand but I don’t think the extension is still called just “Joule’s law” and, more importantly, it is completely clear from the context that the question is not about the extended version.